# Cómo mostar un HTML que recibo después de hacer una petición con axios?

Tags: javascript, express, axios, get, handlebars

Tengo un servidor con express que envía como respuesta un HTML para mostrarlo al cliente.
Cuando hago la petición desde el navegador se muestra correctamente el HTML y puede verlo el cliente.
Pero quiero saber cómo puedo mostrarlo cuando hago la petición con axios desde un archivo index.html?

Agradezco mucho su ayuda!

Adjunto el servidor que escucha la petición GET con express en Node.js
app.js que usa handlebars

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const handlebars = require('handlebars');
const fs = require('fs');

const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/:nombre', (req, res) => {

  fs.readFile('./public/index.html', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    const markup = '<h2><img src="https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/JSDemos/images/widgets/HtmlEditor.svg" alt="HtmlEditor"> Formatted Text</h2>';
   
    const template = handlebars.compile(data);
   
    const result = template({ markup })

       res.send(result);

  });
});
```

index.html que hace la petición

```
    <button id="button"> EDITOR DE TEXTO </button>

    <script>    
        const boton = document.getElementById('button')
        .addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/hola`)
            .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data)
          })
        })
    </script>
```

Esta es la respuesta del servidor, que muestro en consola.
Lo que quiero es mostrarle al cliente este HTML completo, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>CodePen - Output Formats - DevExtreme Html Editor</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/22.2.3/css/dx.light.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
  <div class="dx-viewport demo-container">
    <div class="html-editor"></div>
    <div class="button-container">
      <div class="buttons-column">
        <div class="column-header"> Normal </div>
        <div>
          <div id="normal-contained"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons-column">
        <div class="column-header"> Danger </div>
        <div>
          <div id="danger-outlined"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/devextreme-quill@1.5.18/dist/dx-quill.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/turndown@7.1.1/dist/turndown.js'></script>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/devextreme-showdown@1.0.1/dist/showdown.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/22.2.3/js/dx.all.js'></script>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/prettier@2.7.1/standalone.js'></script>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/prettier@2.7.1/parser-html.js'></script>

  <script>
    var markup = '<h2><img src="https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/JSDemos/images/widgets/HtmlEditor.svg" alt="HtmlEditor"> Formatted Text Editor (HTML Editor)</h2><p><br></p><p>DevExtreme JavaScript HTML Editor is a client-side WYSIWYG text editor that allows its users to format textual and visual content and store it as HTML or Markdown.</p>'
  </script>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de esta forma con [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

En tu cliente creas un `div` donde vas a mostrar la respuesta de la consulta:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

Y en tu script lo siguiente:

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/hola`)
  .then((res) => {
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = res.data;
  })
```

Otra opción sería mostrar la respuesta en un `iframe`, en este caso el `iframe` se comportaría como una ventana independiente.

En el html:

```
<iframe id="content" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-forms allow-modals"></iframe>
```

En tu script:

```
 axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/hola`)
  .then((res) => {
    const iframe = document.getElementById('content');
    iframe.contentDocument.open();
    iframe.contentDocument.write(res.data);
    iframe.contentDocument.close();
  });
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero no me sirvió. Me aparece el siguiente error en consola: `Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/Simulacion_sistema/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.`

Comment: @ZCH Esto sucede porque el html tiene referencias a un archivo css, lo que podrías hacer es eliminar esas referencias para mostrar el html, serían las etiquetas <link>. O incluso enviar el css en la misma consulta

Comment: No puedo eliminar esas referencias. Por eso en la pregunta inicial cité la respuesta del servidor. @EdwardRomero sabes cómo puedo hacerlo con esas referencias?

Comment: @ZCH otra opción que veo es la de usar un iframe, no sé qué opinas?

Comment: Nuevamente gracias por responder, lo que pasa es que no sé utilizar un iframe, conoces alguna forma o otra solución que me pueda servir?

Comment: Claro que sí, ya agrego la opción al comentario

Comment: No funcionó @EdwardRomero. Te adjunto los mensajes en la consola
1) Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/Simulacion_sistema/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
2) GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/Simulacion_sistema/script.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
 
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ index.html:130
3) Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/Simulacion_sistema/script.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141994/discussion-between-edward-romero-and-zch).